# How can I use void printMatrix( ostream& os = cout ) const?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++, and I've got a task, to do some printing with this function, and I don't understand how to use the ostream. Can anyone help me please?

```
    void Matrix::printMatrix( ostream& os = cout ) const{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      for(int j=0; i<m; j++)
        os<<elements[i][j]<<"\n";
    }
```

I've tried to do this, but it threw me some errors, and I don't know how to handle this.
The errors:

Matrix.cpp:47:48: error: default argument given for parameter 1 of ‘void Matrix::printMatrix(std::ostream&) const’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from Matrix.cpp:8:0:
Matrix.h:25:10: error: after previous specification in ‘void Matrix::printMatrix(std::ostream&) const’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: Do you have an `#include <iostream>` directive? And did you import the names from the `std` namespace into the global namespace? The simplest way is to do `using namespace std`, but that's bad programming practice. Try using fully qualified names: `std::cout` and `std::ostream` instead of just `cout` and `ostream`

Comment: i've included <iostream>, and I have the using namespace std included in the code to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should **not** specify the default argument of a function *both* in a declaration and in a definition:

```
class Matrix
{
    // ...

    // Default argument specified in the declaration...
    void printMatrix( ostream& os = cout ) const;

    // ...
};

// ...so you shouldn't (cannot) specify it also in the definition,
// even though you specify the exact same value.
void Matrix::printMatrix( ostream& os /* = cout */ ) const{
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                    Remove this


    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep the default argument specification in the definition and omit it in the declaration. What's important is that you don't have it in both.

Answer (score 3):

The function has an output stream as parameter, and has the standard output (`std::cout`) as default (albeit incorrectly specified in the function definition, not in the declaration as it should be). You can do this:

```
// use default parameter std::cout
Matrix m + ...;
m.printMatrix();

// explicitly use std::cout
m.printMatrix(std::cout);

// write to a file
std::ofstream outfile("matrix.txt");
m.printMatrix(outfile);
```

Comment: No, it does not require it. That's what the `os = cout` does; it provides a default value if no output stream is provided.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I guess that was a reply to some comment that disappeared?

Comment: No. It was a response to the first line of your answer.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart You're right. I had tried to make the usage clear in the code sample but the leading sentence was confusing.